# Safari Top Sites auto-refresh

Tags: safari

It seems that Safari 7.0 (for Mac) doesn't refresh the previews (anymore). Is there a way to turn this (back) on?

Answer (score 1):

You can hit cmd+R while viewing Top Sites to manually refresh.

((I'm still trying to figure out how to restore automatic refresh.))

Answer (score 1):

It is now no longer possible to refresh the Top Sites with Cmd-R (certainly it doesn't work in Safari 10.)

The only way I've found to do it is:

- Enable the Develop menu (Preferences->Advanced->Show Develop menu in menu bar)
- Choose Develop->Empty Caches

This will clear all Safari caches including Top Sites. The Top Sites thumbnails will gradually fill back in with newly-refreshed versions. (Very gradually—I assume Safari does it quietly and in the background, while it's idle. It took about five minutes for a new Top Sites tab I opened to gradually fill its thumbnails in as I was doing other things.)

This doesn't re-enable the "auto refresh" there used to be, but hopefully it might help someone like me who had a temporary network issue that seemed to corrupt all the Top Site thumbnails and just wants to force a refresh from scratch.